# Google Analytics react-ga4 returning a 204 but event not tracking

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics

I am trying to log events using `react-ga4`.

After firing an event I get a response.

```
Headers:
Request URL:
https://www.google-analytics.com/g/collect?....
Request Method:POST
Status Code:204
Remote Address:142....
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Request Payload:
en=header_about_us_click&_ee=1&ep.category=button&ep.action=click&_et=2929
en=page_view&_ee=1&_et=2&dp=%2Fwho-we-are&dt=About%20Us&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.paragonwebdevelopment.com%2Fwho-we-are
```

The request payload seems to be correct. However it doesn't seem like my events are tracking correctly.

Comment: how do you know there not?

Comment: I am watching the real time event tracking in google analytics. It seems like events only track around 40% of the time.